# Dedenting multiple lines fail when code is collapsed - vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, code-folding

As seen in the gif when the code is collapsed and I try to dedent it, the content inside `{}` doesn't move, is it a bug or there's a special shortcut to dedent the lines in this case?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this code folding is in vanilla vscode(or the C++ extension), what extension is this from?